# Fibers of polynomial as submanifold

Tags: analysis, manifolds

Let $f\in \mathbb{R}[X_1,...,X_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. Let $F_{a}=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n : f(x_1,...,x_n)=a\}$. For which $a$ $F_a$ is a submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Edit:
So, let $f=\sum_{i_1+...+i_n=d}A_{i_1...i_n}X_1^{i_1}...X_{n}^{i_n}$. Define $F:=f-a$. Then we should find all $a$ such that $\nabla F\neq0 $. We have that $\partial_{x_j}F=\sum_{i_1+...+i_n=d}A_{i_1...i_n}X_1^{i_1}...X_{j-1}^{i_{j-1}}X_{j}^{i_j -1}X_{j+1}^{i_{j+1}}...X_{n}^{i_n}$.

What is the simplest method to find zeros of $\nabla F$ ?

Comment: Could you please say a little about (i) What tools you have available, (ii) What type of criteria you hope to find (and why), and (iii) What approaches you've thought of or tried yourself?

Comment: I can use any tool. I am looking for the simplest solution. I tried to examine rank of differential and tried to use criterion of being locally graph of some function.

Comment: The sets $F_a$ are often called "level curves", even when the dimension $n-1$ isn't actually 1.

Comment: So, I should find all $a$ such that $\mathrm{grad}(f-a)\neq 0$. Is it any fast method to do it in this case ?

Comment: @mikis: The only general criterion that comes to mind is what you suggest: Looking for zeros of the gradient and invoking the implicit function theorem. (That's a sufficient condition, but not necessary; $X_{1}^{n} = 0$ defines a hyperplane even though the gradient vanishes along the zero set if $n \geq 2$.)